# `module.exports = function` testability

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, design-patterns

Say I want to create a pipeline that chain multiple transform functions, and put each transform function in its own file.

While I prefer each of them to export function, it seems like a bad idea to do `module.exports = function transform` because we can only test them like blackbox? While `module.exports = constructor Transform` look more testable given we can expose instance properties.

So I usually end up writing a wrapper like

```
var SomeClass = require('./lib/some-class');

module.exports = factory;

function factory(options) {
  var instance = new SomeClass(options);
  //... more work
  return instance;
}
```

Then test `SomeClass` separately.

**While this works, is it a good pattern?** I would like my main `pipeline.js` to only call functions, instead of having to know how to `new` and run each Class, because pipeline should only know them as simple transform function, ie. `f(X) -> Y`.